# How to Send file field using jquery ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=account/edit',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('#account_edit input[type=\'text\'], #account_edit input[type=\'password\'],**#account_edit input[type=\'file\']**,#account_edit input[type=\'radio\']:checked'),
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#button-update').attr('disabled', true);
            $('#button-update').after('<span class="wait">&nbsp;<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/loading.gif" alt="" /></span>');
        },  
        complete: function() {
            $('#button-update').attr('disabled', false); 
            $('.wait').remove();
        },          
        success: function(json) {
            $('.warning').remove();
            $('.error').remove();
            //alert(json['error']['firstname']);

            if (json['redirect']) {
                //location = json['redirect'];
            }

}
```

Comment: please add some problem description.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492617/how-can-i-upload-a-file-using-jquerys-ajax-function-with-json-and-php?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I have used the [jQuery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) to submit files in an ajax-like manner, specifically the [.ajaxSubmit()](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#api) method.

Answer (score 0):

$.ajax() does not support file uploading. Better you should try some plugins like [ajaxForm](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#getting-started) to upload files.