# File upload inside JSON

Tags: php, json, api, rest

I'm building a REST API Service using PHP. I know how to receive file in standard html form(multipart/form-data).

But in my service I want to use json. So the question is, how to upload file when the client use Content-Type:application-json? How to embed a file in JSON?

Or is there some other or standard way that I must follow regarding REST API design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to encode your file as a string (e.g. in base64) and put this string in your JSON as a JSON value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. btw, is there any REST API provider using this method(encode as base64) for uploading file ?

Comment: Well, this is [the way CouchDB handles "inline attachments"](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API#Inline_Attachments).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's a few answers to this question already. See the following question:

[How can i upload a file using jquery's $.ajax function with json and php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492617/how-can-i-upload-a-file-using-jquerys-ajax-function-with-json-and-php)

They largely suggest using a plugin.