# How to submit a form containing an image with ajax to Django rest framework?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-rest-framework

Can you spot what I'm doing incorrectly?

Here is the Form (created in a template tag):

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def add_picture_upload(context,textarea_id):
  a = """<form style="display:none; visibility:hidden;" id="add_image_form" action="/fotos/upload/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >""" 
  b = """</form>"""
  form = PictureForm()
  return a+str(form)+b
```

Here the javascript that gets called on submit:

```
function html_add_image(event) {
  event.stopPropagation(); // Stop stuff happening
  event.preventDefault(); // Totally stop stuff happening
  var data_dict = new FormData($(this)[0]);
  var req = api_create("pictures", data_dict);
  req.done(function(data) {
    alert(data);
  })
}
```

Here the ajax request:

```
function api_create(content_name, data_dict) {
  var req = $.ajax({
      url: '/api/'+content_name+'/',
      contentType:"application/json",
      dataType: "json",
      data: data_dict,
      processData: false,
      type: 'POST'
  }).fail(function(jqXHR, status, err){
    // fail
  })
  return req;
}
```

It gives me:

> detail: "JSON parse error - 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in
>   position 148: invalid start byte"

Or if i JSON.stringify the data instead I get:

> image_field: ["No file was submitted."]

Do you have any advice or a website that has a working example? I know many people are struggling with this, but all the other questions here don't really lead anywhere.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django REST Framework upload image: "The submitted data was not a file"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28036404/django-rest-framework-upload-image-the-submitted-data-was-not-a-file)

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to popular belief, [it's not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4083702/359284) to upload files using JSON such that Django can recognize them without hacking around it.  This is because [JSON does not natively support file uploads](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10492617/359284), so you have to handle file serialization and uploading on your own.

But you have a few options

- Handle file uploads separately from the metadata. This would require separate endpoints for the files and the metadata, similar to what Dropbox does with [separating file uploads](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#files_put) and [the metadata](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#metadata).
- Base64-encode the files when you are uploading them, and use a custom `Base64FileField` to handle them. drf-extras provides a [`Base64ImageField`](https://github.com/Hipo/drf-extra-fields) that can be used.